# Bootstrap columns not adjusting to small screen in fancybox window

Tags: ios, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, fancybox-2

I have a site that opens a html document in a fancybox.  The html has two equal columns - so I have two `<div class="col-sm-6">` divs.  The two columns display quite nicely on desktop, and iPad portrait and landscape - but for some reason it doesn't switch to a single column on iphone.  It still displays two columns for both landscape and portait on iphone.

The bootstrap columns work properly on my primary html - but not on the html opened in fancybox.  Any ideas why the html would not be switching to single column on smaller screen.

Fancybox Script

```
<script type = "text/javascript">
  $(function() {
    //    fancybox
    jQuery(".fancybox").fancybox({
      'type': 'iframe', // tell the script to create an iframe
    });
  });
</script>
```

HTML

```
<figure class="effect-jazz">
    <img src="hover/img/6.jpg" alt="img06"/>
        <figcaption>
            <h2>Song <span>List</span></h2>
            <p>View a comprehensive list of songs in Pauls current repertoire.</p>
            <a  class="fancybox fancybox.iframe" href="songlist.html"></a>
        </figcaption>           
</figure>
```

Comment: can you post fancybox script

Comment: why you are creating an iframe, why not inline content?

Comment: What is the difference? The songlist.html pops up over my index.html.  This works as intended BUT it doesn't resize down to 1 column for smaller screens as the bootstrap styling should take care of.  Instead - songlist.html tries to display two columns even on portrait iphone.  I have a number of links on the page that popup using fancybox... some contain youtube video, some soundcloud playlist, and some html files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks #Shehary.  It was indeed the iframe that was the problem. New code in my primary html document:

```html
<figure class="effect-jazz">
  <img src="hover/img/6.jpg" alt="img06" />
  <figcaption>
    <h2>Song <span>List</span></h2>
    <p>View a comprehensive list of songs in Pauls current repertoire.</p>
    <a class="fancybox" href="songlist.html"></a>
  </figcaption>
</figure>
</div>
```

This fancybox now resizes down to 1 column on smaller screens as dictated by bootstrap.
Thanks.